# Marginal distributions of the Indian Buffet Process

Tags: bayesian, poisson-distribution, unsupervised-learning, marginal-distribution, dirichlet-process

In the construction of the Indian Buffet Process we have that customer $n_1$ chooses $\mbox{Poisson}\left(\frac{\alpha}{1}\right)$ dishes, $n_2$ chooses $\mbox{Poisson}\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) \dots n_N$ chooses $\mbox{Poisson}\left(\frac{\alpha}{N}\right)$ dishes, so that the total number of dishes, $K^+$ is the sum of these Poisson random variables such that $K^+ \sim \mbox{Poisson}\left(\alpha\sum_i^N\frac{1}{i}\right)$.

Now, a random binary matrix, $\textbf{Z}$, is said to follow the Indian Buffet Process if
$$
P(\textbf{Z})=\frac{\alpha^{K^+}\exp{\left(\alpha\sum_i^N\frac{1}{i}\right)}}{\prod_i^N K^{(i)}!}\prod_j^{K^{+}}\frac{\left(N-m_j\right)!\left(m_j-1\right)!}{N!}
$$
Where $K^{(i)}$ here is the number of dishes that customer $n_i$ chooses, that is, $K^{(i)}|\alpha \sim \mbox{Poisson}(\frac{\alpha}{i})$.

My question is, how can we derive from $P\left(\textbf{Z}\right)$ that the total number of dishes is such that $K^+ \sim \mbox{Poisson}\left(\alpha\sum_i^N\frac{1}{i}\right)$?

My idea is to think about $P\left(\textbf{Z}\right)$ as being a joint distribution over the dishes a customer chooses, $\vec{\gamma}$, and the total number of unique dishes all customers choose $K^+$, so that we have $P\left(\textbf{Z}\right) = P\left(\vec{\gamma}, K^{+}\right)$ and sum over all $\vec{\gamma}$ to get the marginal distribution $P\left(K^+\right)$ However, it's not clear to me how to actually do this summation just by looking at the expression.

My motivation for this is because I'd like to know how $K^+$ is distributed if I multiply the Indian Buffet Process by some likelihood function. In [1] the authors discuss using the Indian Buffet Process as a prior and use an infinite linear gaussian model as a likelihood but they do not discuss how the distribution of $K^+$ changes with this introduction. Surely if, for example, I add some exponential decay in the trial of new dishes by doing something like $A\cdot P\left(Z\right)e^{-K^+}$ (where $A$ is some normalizing constant) then in this model $K^+$ is *not* $\mbox{Poisson}\left(\alpha\sum_i^N\frac{1}{i}\right)$ distributed. How can I analytically derive the distribution of $K^+$ in this case?

[1] https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume12/griffiths11a/griffiths11a.pdf

Comment: Hi: I don't know the answer to your second question but, for the first part, the sum of 2 posson RV's with rates $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ respectively, is still poisson with rate $\lambda_1$ + $\lambda_2$. If you google, I'm sure the proof of this is on the net. So, once you have that result, by induction, you can see how the distribution of $K^{+}$ arises.